# Add local dependency jar in SBT-Scalatra project

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

I am working on a sample scalatra webapp. I have created one more service jar which contains dao and service layer. I want to add this dependency  in Scalatra-SBT project. How can i achieve this?

I bundled my service jar using command : **SBT package** which created a jar. How will i include this jar in web application? Can i add this in build.scala file? or can i copy into any Webapp folder ?

Is it possible to push this jar to local repository and pull it from there when my webapp builds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whew! Lots of questions here!

The good news is that SBT can do all of the tasks that you are asking for.

***DO NOT* copy JAR files around to satisfy dependencies!** It will end up in tears, virtually guaranteed. Tools like Ivy and Maven (and by extension, SBT) are here to help.

**To push your service jar to a local repo:**

The SBT task is `publish-local`, i.e. `sbt publish-local` from your service jar's root directory.
You'll see lots of descriptive output, finishing up with lines in the following format:

`[info] published services_2.10 to /Users/millhouse/.ivy2/local/services/services_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/services_2.10.jar`

You don't need to do anything special in your `build.sbt` to make this work, as long as you have the `name` and `scalaVersion` variables set. Note that this will publish to your local Ivy cache, which is `$HOME/.ivy2/local` for most people.

**To get your Scalatra-SBT webapp to pick up your service jar:**

Edit your webapp's `project/build.scala`, adding this dependency under the `libraryDependencies` key (there should already be a few dependencies, one per line, put yours somewhere in the middle!):

`"services" %% "services" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT",`

Perform an `sbt clean update` and your dependency will be pulled in. If it doesn't work, SBT will give you a list of the places where it looked for the artifacts; compare it closely with the location that they were published to (in the previous step) and you'll probably find a typo; fix it and try again.

Please note that there is a *lot* more to dependency and release management than I've shown above, but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: I got this solution after reading sbt documentation. I did the same way as you answered. Anyway thank you for answering

Comment: @rajeevprasanna would you mind linking that documentation page?